# Overriding application settings

Tags: c#, class-library, application-settings

I have a solution which has a **WinForm** application (Project 1) which makes use of a **Class2** from another Class Library project (Project 2). Project 2 makes use of a **class3** which is defined in another Class Library project (Project 3).

I know I can override application settings of Project 2 from my Main WinForm application, but, **my question is**, can I override application settings which were defined in Class Library Project (Project 3) from my main WinForm application (Project 1)

I know it looks like Im making things complicated, but I had to override application settings of Project 3 from my main application.

Can anyone put some light in this direction and suggest how to resolve this?

FYI...

When you add a setting.settings file, it will automatically creates a app.config file and we can configure applicationSettings from Setting.settings UI in VS. Below is the app.config file content from Project3 whose applicationSettings Im interested to override in another WinForm project.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Project3.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Project3.Settings>
            <setting name="SettingInProject3" serializeAs="String">
                <value>TempPath</value>
            </setting>
        </Project3.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

What modifications in app.config file of WinForm application can override the settings defined in Project3 class library.

The hierarchy of references goes something like this. WinForm>Project2DLL>Project3DLL.

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: please show some code

Comment: I am having this exact issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the settings in the source project in visual studio, Ensure the Access modifier (at the top) in the settings viewer in visual studio is set to public. Now these settings will be accessible from your external projects.

Comment: Hi Reckface, Thank you very much for the response. Yes, it will work fine.

But, In my case, I have to override settings of Project3 dll whose reference is given in Project2 dll whose reference is added in my main WinForm project where I should override applicationSetting in its app.config file.

Please let me know if this information is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried adding project 3 as reference in project 1? Or write a settings manager class in project 2 that gives you access to the settings in project 3. It would need a public property and a public Save method to save the underlying changes.

Comment: That's a nice idea to start with. 

So, if I save the changes using settings manager class, would those changes be reflected in app.config file of project3 or will they be saved in AppData?

Just curious to know because I should be able to drive these changes via updating the app.config ONLY.

Thanks for the time.